# Use Delegate result as input in C# 2.0

Tags: c#, delegates

I have `List<T>` and I want to find two random name from that `List<T>` starting with some condition from List using .NET 2.0.

I know its very easy with LINQ but I am stuck with 2.0

I am wondering if I can do something like this

```
List<foo> list = new List<foo>();
List<foo> newlist = new List<foo>();
Random r = new Random();

list.Add(new foo("1"));
list.Add(new foo("A91"));
list.Add(new foo("A01"));
list.Add(new foo("A71"));
list.Add(new foo("B02"));
list.Add(new foo("B2"));
list.Add(new foo("B03"));
list.Add(new foo("23"));
list.Add(new foo("24"));

string[] searchList = { "A", "B", "C",};

foreach (string name in searchList)
{
   List<foo> templist = list.FindAll(delegate (foo f)
                        {
                             List<foo> templist1 = f.Name.StartsWith(name);
                             {
                                if(templist1.Count>0)
                               {
                                  while (templist.Count != 0)
                                 {
                                    ??.Add(templist1[r.Next(templist1.Count)]);

                                 }
                              retrun ??
                            }
                       }
                       });


 }
```

Comment: BTW, you can develop on .NET 3.5 (i.e by using C# 3.0) almost  without lost compatibility (Changes in the .NET BCL between 2.0 and 3.5 http://bit.ly/bDkD6Y / The Moth - .NET Framework 3.5 http://bit.ly/bd1AiD). You could even use LINQ just deploy with your binary System.Core assembly (LINQ support on .NET 2.0 -  http://bit.ly/cq6Gvj)

Comment: Can you explain what return value you are expecting for tempList, are you asking for shuffled list of values that start with the prefix?

Comment: @Sam Saffron : I want two values from list where name start with a b and c. I am expection templist should have 4 values,two random values start with A and two random value start with B.

Answer (score 1):

Putting aside that the way I'd personally approach being restricted to .NET 2.0 is by using the 3.5 System.Core dll and copying local (as mentioned by Nick Martyshchenko)...

The actual problem here seems to be that you are not returning the correct type in your anonymous delegate `List<T>.FindAll` takes a `Predicate<T>` delegate. Predicate returns a `bool`.

`List<T>.FindAll` is NOT like the LINQ where method at all. It is not lazy. That is, it is not an IEnumerable that yields on enumeration. FindAll returns a `List<T>` (already enumerated).

Maybe I'm not understanding your requirements here, but why not do this:

```
List<foo> templist = list.FindAll(delegate (foo f)
                    {
                         bool itemStartsWith = f.Name.StartsWith(name);

                         if(itemStartsWith)
                         {
                            return true;
                         }
                         return false;
                    });
```

Comment: I may be misunderstanding but I think the op wants this list shuffled after the fact

Answer (score 0):

Not `return`, but [`yield return`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).

Comment: isn't `yield return` a C# 3.0 feature?

Comment: No, it seems that VS2005 (.net 2.0) supports it.  Click on link (I updated it)

Comment: Yield cannot be used inside an an anonymous method (compiler error) (from your link)

Comment: Well then, if he wants to use that kind of structure, will have to sacrifice anonymous method and move to real method...